# Datatype for saving GPS data in MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, geolocation

My Quest:What data type should I use?

I want to upload the gps data into my MySQL DB. I also don't know how long the `longitude` or `latitude` can be. Is it better to use `VARCHAR`.

I don't want to use `POINT` because of some parse problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use as FLOAT( 9 , 6 ) NOT NULL.

Also check out this :- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html

May be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can multiply latitude and longitude x 10^6 and storage it as INT

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data type `Decimal(9,6)`. One for latitude and one for longitude.

Hope this helps.